# Unable to add custom menu to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script that will download sheets as individual CSV's, however i cant get the script to run past 'addToUi' or 'addMenu' related. I'm operating off work servers but we permissions have been granted.

see below snippets of code I've tried to far:

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "export as csv files", functionName: "saveAsCSV"}];
ss.addMenu("csv", csvMenuEntries);
};
```

I've also tried:

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
.createMenu('Bulk Export Wok Sheets')
.addItem('Parent Chain',SACSV);
.addToUi();

}
```

I've tried a direct copy from Apps Script Developer guide:

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
  .addSeparator()
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
      .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2'))
  .addToUi();
  }

 function menuItem1() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
 .alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
 }

 function menuItem2() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
 .alert('You clicked the second menu item!');
 }
```

Comment: Is it a [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) script, or [standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)? You  can only make this work if using a bound script.

Comment: @Diego this is a bound script written in Google Apps Script

Answer (score 0):

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("My Menu").addItem('Description', 'funcname').addToUi();
```

[createMenu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#createMenu(String))

This one should work like this:

```
function onOpen() {
//I removed the semicolons from the chain which will keep it from working.
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
.createMenu('Bulk Export Wok Sheets')
.addItem('Parent Chain','SACSV')
.addToUi();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, it still returns "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 4, file "Code")Dismiss
"

Comment: Where are you trying to call it from?

Comment: Did you open the Spreadsheet with `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`?

Comment: I'd start with another spreadsheet and recopy the scripts over to it.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to share the spreadsheet so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Try using `.openById()` as Cooper suggested and make sure you aren't running this on a time trigger as `.getUi()` can only be called on a user-driven action.

Comment: I've managed to get around it using you coopers code, i also suspect trying to operate this script on a work laptop had something to do with it. I tried the original code on a personal computer and it worked instantly. Thank you for your help!